# Bash: save result of python code to bash script and write result to file

Tags: bash, shell

This bash script is supposed to do the following:

1) Read in two values, `susc` and `exp_trans` from a file `postprocessing.txt`

2) Pass in those two values as command-line inputs to the Python program `postproc.py`

3) Save the result of `postproc.py` as `varval`. This is a list of three values.

4) Create a file with headers `M1, M2, M3`, and write `varval` values under each.

There's some `cd`ing along the way, but I'm not getting what I expect here. Here's what I expect:

```
M1 M2 M3
[[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]
[[5.3], [2.1111111111111111], [0.59111111111111111]]
```

Here's what I get:

```
[[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]
M1,M2,M3
[[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]
./postproc.sh: line 6: [[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]+1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]+1"
```

So clearly something's wrong with how I'm iterating, because I'm only getting one result from `postproc.py` instead of two. I think the error lies in this line: `varval=$(python ../postproc.py --susc $a1 --exp_trans $b1 2>&1)`

Does anyone know how to save results, in a loop, in bash, and then write them to a file?

My bash code:

```
#/bin/bash

i=0
while read a1 b1
    do
    i=$(($i+1))
    cd RUN_EXP$i
    varval=$(python ../postproc.py --susc $a1 --exp_trans $b1 2>&1)
    echo $varval
    cd ..
    echo M1,M2,M3
        for i in "${varval[@]}"
        do
                echo $i
        done
    done < postprocessing.txt
```

**EDIT**

It's not just the `i` being overwritten (good catch though, thank you!). After fixing that per the answers by Veselin Ivanov and micebrain below, the output is still not quite right.

The code so far:

```
#/bin/bash

i=0
echo M1,M2,M3
while read a1 b1
    do
    i=$(($i+1))
    cd RUN_EXP$i
    varval=$(python ../postproc.py --susc $a1 --exp_trans $b1 2>&1)
    echo $varval
    cd ..
        for j in "${varval[@]}"
        do
                echo $j
        done
    done < postprocessing.txt
```

The output:

```
 M1,M2,M3
[[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]
[[4.0], [2.2799999999999998], [0.56000000000000005]]
[[5.3], [2.1111111111111111], [0.59111111111111111]]
[[5.3], [2.1111111111111111], [0.59111111111111111]]
```

Comment: `for i in "${varval[@]}"` Really?

Comment: Why are you running your python script with ../? Can you not put a #! in your Python script pointing it to the Python executable?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Really really....is there another way?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Because it's stored one directory up. Why the change?

Comment: Have you read the code? Did you look at what you're already using?

Comment: It's not good practice. Enter the full path to the script instead

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I accept I'm probably doing something silly. I don't understand your question, though. Could you please explain why the `for` loop is incorrect?

Comment: You're already using `$i` for something else.

Comment: Oh yeah, I fixed that already. Please see the edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the variable **i** again and on the second run it's a string not an integer.Just rename it with j for example like this :

```
#/bin/bash

i=0
while read a1 b1
    do
    i=$(($i+1))
    cd RUN_EXP$i
    varval=$(python ../postproc.py --susc $a1 --exp_trans $b1 2>&1)
    echo $varval
    cd ..
    echo M1,M2,M3
        for j in "${varval[@]}"
        do
                echo $j
        done
    done < postprocessing.txt
```

EDIT :

If you want to do it with an array and print each entry in a separate line (I assume you want to do this) then this is a way to do it.

```
#/bin/bash

i=0
echo M1,M2,M3
while read a1 b1
    do
    i=$(($i+1))
    cd RUN_EXP$i
    varval=$(python ../postproc.py --susc $a1 --exp_trans $b1 2>&1)

    field1=$(echo $varval|cut -d ',' -f1)
    field2=$(echo $varval|cut -d ',' -f2)
    field3=$(echo $varval|cut -d ',' -f3)

    values=($field1,$field2,$field3)
    cd ..
    echo M1,M2,M3
        for j in "${values[@]}"
        do
                echo $j
        done
    done < postprocessing.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't the only error. Please see the update.

Comment: Well if you are worried about the redundant entry that's because you are printing $varval and $j which have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting the variable i by reusing it in the for loop. Also the echo for the header should be before the while loop.